# How to open Azure website in local machine?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, network-security-groups

I have hosted my website on an Azure virtual machine. I can open my website on that virtual machine without any issues, but I cannot open the same website on my laptop. What is the reason for this?

I have created New rules in Network Security Group to allow port 80 and 443. But still, it's not working.

Comment: Did you check the firewall on the virtual machine? Also make sure the server is actually listening for connections from outside and not just on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Hosted sample IIS website on an Azure virtual machine I got the same error like below:

[image]

This error usually occurs, in virtual machine network security group not associated with your virtual machine to allows inbound traffic on ports 80 and 443.

Added ports 80 and 443 in my virtual machine.

[image]

When I added port, I got result successfully like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/gceZy9i.png)]

In your case as you added port 80 and 443 ensure that the firewall on your Azure VM is not blocking incoming traffic on ports 80 and 443.

***Open the Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security application -> inbound port rule, right click add new rule with port like below:***

[image]

Make sure to check port is allowing on your vm using `Telnet`

```
Telnet <ipadress> 80
```

[image]

Ensure that your web server running on the Azure VM is correctly configured to listen on port 80 like below:

[image]

If you are unable to access the application which is hosted in vm try to access in another network or location